# How can I increase the speed of my object like with levels in a game?

Tags: python, function, variables, position, turtle-graphics

in my code, which is for a game, I want to increase the speed of my randomly moving object ( here I call it squidward ) every time a certain amount of clicks and level is reached. However, my function is not working. I think the function itself makes sense and maybe I forgot to add something, however, I looked over it several times, but at this point I don't know what else I could possibly do in order to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle 
from tkinter import* 
from random import randint 


# set up 
win =  turtle.Screen()
win.title("Squid-game")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.register_shape("squid_big.gif") 

# variabelen 
clicks = -1 
level = 1 
Speed = 1


  
 
# dem Turtle-objekt in Thadäus formen 
squidward = turtle.Turtle()
squidward.shape("squid_big.gif")
squidward.penup()
squidward.speed(Speed)


def Speed():
     global Speed, level, clicks 
     if level == 1 and clicks == 5: 
          level += 1  
          Speed += 1 
     if level == 2 and clicks == 10: 
          level += 1 
          Speed += 5 
     if level == 3 and clicks == 15: 
          level += 1 
          Speed += 2 
          squidward.speed(Speed)

squidward.onclick(Speed())

# zeigt an wie viele Clicks man hat 
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.color("white")
pen.penup 
pen.goto(0, 400)
pen.write (f"Clicks: {clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))

# Funtion für das Clicken und den random Bewegung 
def clicked (x,y): 
     global clicks 
     clicks += 1 
     pen.clear() 
     pen.write (f"Clicks: {clicks}", align="center", font=("Courier New", 32, "normal"))
     while TRUE:  squidward.goto(randint(-1200, 1200), randint(-1200, 1200)) 

# die Geschwindigkeit muss ich ab einer bestimmten Aazahl bis 10 steigen// Level-up 


squidward.onclick(clicked)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes in that you only define the speed of the turtle once. Instead you should reset the speed every level like so;

```py
    def Speed():
         global Speed, level, clicks, squidward 
         if level == 1 and clicks == 5: 
              level += 1  
              Speed += 1 

         if level == 2 and clicks == 10: 
              level += 1 
              Speed += 5 

         if level == 3 and clicks == 15: 
              level += 1 
              Speed += 2 
         squidward.speed(Speed)
```

In addition, the clicked() function is never ended as it goes into an infinite loop